# Web how to prevent security problems caused by modifying element attribute values?like disabled or hide

Tags: java, security, web

I have a website that uses **java** and **angularjs** . Because of security requirements, how can I prevent security issues caused by modifying the disabled or hide attributes value of an element on Web?

eg:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="true" data-ng-model="model.username" id="username"name="username"/>
</div>
```

then through F12 change to `ng-disabled="false"` or `ng-hide="false"`,now I can edit username or other important items.

so, how can I do to avoid that?

Comment: You have to double check the data sended to your server (in server side). It's the only way to be secure. Then, if you need to send sensitive data (like username) through a simple form, it will not be secured at all. This kind of information needs to be sended/retrieved via an authentication system. Take a look at token based authentication system (JWT for ex).

Answer (score 0):

In web development with frameworks like AngularJS, ReactJS or any other Front-end Frameworks you need to remember one thing. everything that happens in the frontend is just for the convenience of the user.

Evey data entered by the users can be (and will be) manipulated. So you need to validate everything in the backend app as for the validation in the frontend is just for the convenience of the user.

If he chooses to disable your javascript validation process in **his** web browser you can't stop him if he chooses to execute some random script on his web browser you can't stop him. The only thing you can do is verify every input in your backend.